# How to Access Ubuntu Files From Bootable USB "Try Ubuntu" Section

Tags: boot, usb, system-installation, backup

Few hours ago I have tried to open my pc but I got error called "BOOTMGR IS MISSING" please restart pc, after little research I thought that I should create bootable Ubuntu USB and access my ubuntu files and backup some of them. (I dont have a Windows 7 cd so I can't repair the system).

I plugged in the USB and wait for Ubuntu panel 2 options were there -> "Try Ubuntu" and "Install Ubuntu" so I clicked First One and bootable Ubuntu opened (*where I'm writing this problem) but I could not find ubuntu files I can only see my windows 7 files when search.

Where can I get ubuntu files so I can get backup and re-install windows or repair it?

Comment: Can you open Nautilus, the Folder icon on the left panel on the desktop and describe what you see on the left panel of the program window? You should see one or more some icons that look like hard disks. Try clicking them.

Comment: There are "Places", "Devices" and "Network" in Devices -> "308GB Volume" and "Computer" what should i do ?

Comment: Is this a Windows only laptop? Try clicking on the 308GB volume. That is the drive of the laptop. If the hard drive itself is not broken, you should be able to click through to the folder(s) you want to backup. Copy the flies and folders in another USB drive (not the one you have booted from).

Comment: I can see files but i want to choose ubuntu files specifically do you know the path that ubuntu files located ?

Comment: What do you mean by "Ubuntu Files?" Do you mean the Operating System, the programs that come with it, or the data, like photos and music?

Comment: Data such as files,photos , folders , downloads.....

Comment: Those should be under /home/[userID]/. Look for a folder called home, inside it there should be folder(s) by the name(s) of your user(s).

Answer (score 0):

Install GParted and check whether you can get your stuff back.

```
sudo apt-get install gparted
```

Do you have Boot-repair installed? With that, you can repair your BOOTMGR.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo set 's/trusty/saucy/g' -i /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yannubuntu-boot-repair- trusty.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && (boot-repair &)
```

Comment: i dont have boot-repair beacuse i'm running ubuntu from bootable usb right now so how can i install that boot-repair

Comment: With the command I given you above.

Comment: Getting this:  Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/yannubuntu/boot-repair/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

Comment: Changed the code, try that one.

Comment: Getting that now: sudo sed 's/trusty/saucy/g' -i /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yannubuntu-boot-repair- trusty.list
sed: can't read /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yannubuntu-boot-repair-: No such file or directory
sed: can't read trusty.list: No such file or directory

Comment: Are you entering all commands, line by line?

Comment: yes,i am doing double check and getting the same error

Comment: Try `sudo set 's/trusty/saucy/g' -i /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yannubuntu-boot-repair- trusty.list`

Comment: Says: command not found ??

Comment: Don't have any idea for now, try the first option.