# Possible to access files from "Try Ubuntu"? I tried GParted and the Disks tool. Both were dead ends for me (or I didnt receive proper guidance)

Tags: partitioning, usb, gparted

I have a Ubuntu machine that may need reformatting. I would like to rescue my files. I have an Ubuntu 22.04 boot USB to work with and another USB to copy my files to.

I heard from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1164653/i-want-to-copy-my-home-folder-to-a-usb-flash-drive-but-i-cant-i-accidentally-r) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1140568/how-to-access-home-files-from-try-ubuntu) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/474568/how-to-access-ubuntu-files-from-bootable-usb-try-ubuntu-section) that it may be possible using either Nautilus or GParted or the Ubuntu "Disks" tool. All of these tools are new to me as of today. I tried GParted and Disks. GParted gave me a GUI I didn't understand. The Disks tool, I managed to "mount" a partition at `/media/ubuntu/9023-2B09` but when I went to that folder, I did not see a `/home` as I expected. Instead I saw a bunch of short jibberish strings of text as file names that I don't remember.

Would someone please write a solution for this for Ubuntu 22.04? My Googling lead me to those AskUbuntu posts but no other even semi-useful information. It was pretty sparse or else my queries just weren't good.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `nautilus` is the GNOME File browser (see https://wiki.gnome.org/action/show/Apps/Files?action=show&redirect=Apps%2FNautilus) being the *simple file manager for GNOME* (it'll be on your 22.04 ISO even if called *files*). It's hard to help with "*jibberish strings of text*" however unless you provide that text.  Myself I'd use a terminal to mount` etc. but your duplicate links seem fine to me, so specific details on what you tried & where you get stuck maybe required to provide help (inc. links to where you've stored images if it's hard to describe).

Comment: It sounds like you didn't mount the correct partition, or the partition you mounted is corrupt. Could you edit your question to include the full output of the terminal, including commands you ran?